# Changed LESS-files not automatically recompiling in node/express/coffee setup

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, express, less

After finally getting LESS-compiling into a Node.js app with express running on coffee, I ran into a problem where I seem to be running out of ideas:

**Changes to the LESS-files will not invoke re-rendering from the LESS-compiler called by express.**

In my main app.coffee file, this can be found (in that order)

```
app.use exp.compiler { src: __dirname + '/public', dest: __dirname + '/public', enable: ['less'] }
app.use exp.methodOverride()
app.use exp.bodyParser()
app.use exp.cookieParser()
app.use exp.static __dirname + '/public'
```

After that, session and middleware is added.

The problem with not recompiling .less files into .css when requested persists through app restarts.

I have tried swapping the `exp.compiler` and `exp.static` lines, but that changed nothing apart from what happens to the first client request (in short, css file is rendered but not delivered).

Deleting the .css file will obviously get the code to recompile the .less into .css, but that is not how I imagined a compiler like that. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: I would have advised you to use the command line `lessc` program, but it doesn't seem to have a watch mode either.

Comment: wild guesses, but try checking your file permissions and putting the compiler line right before `express.static`

Comment: that also has no effect on the recompiling. i think i could probably write a workaround, deleting all css files before launching the main app file.. but this looks like more of a hack than a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Environment Respective Less Watch Script
if (app.settings.env === 'development') {
  var stylesheets = fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'stylesheets')).filter(function(f) {
    return f.match(/\.less$/);
  });
  stylesheets.forEach(function(f) {
    fs.watchFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views', 'stylesheets', '/' + f), function(c, p) {
      if (c.mtime.getTime() !== p.mtime.getTime()) {
        // Remove the existing CSS file
        fs.unlinkSync(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'stylesheets', 'bootstrap.css'));
        console.log(' Successfully removed existing stylesheet for recompiling');
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Research shows that right now, no `-watch`-flag works with the compilers within express or `lessc`. So recompiling inside express works only if the css-Files are manually removed beforehand.

Comment: You should enter the versions you are using for node, express, and less. I'm able to get it to watch my .less files with the following versions:
    "express": ">= 2.5.9 < 3.0.0",
    "coffee-script": ">=1.1.3 < 2.0.0",
    "less": ">=1.3.0 < 2.0.0"